# Unable to use variables (declared WebElement) with final keyword from Superclass in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a superclass and my intention is to declare the WebElement in one class as final and use them in the subclass.

Below is the parent class name ***ObjectRepo*** where I have declared all the WebElement path. I am trying to use the elements in the subclass, but I see Nullpointer exception at runtime.

The code worked earlier when all the `driver.findElements` were within the code, but the issue started when I separated it in a different class. I could figure its due to the driver being null, but unable to fix it.

I see the null pointer error on  the first line of super class--

```
final WebElement SignIn_SignUp_button = ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='SIGN IN / SIGN UP']"));
```

I tried checking if at any point my driver is null and fixing it but didn't work.

Parent class:

```
public class ObjectRepo {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public ObjectRepo()
    {

        // ------------- UIElement of the page ------
        final WebElement SignIn_SignUp_button = ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='SIGN IN / SIGN UP']"));
        final WebElement EmailField_OnSignIn =ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']"));
        final WebElement ContinueButton_OnSignIn=ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Continue']"));
        final WebElement PasswordField_OnSignIn=ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Enter your password']"));
        final WebElement ContinueButton_OnPasswordPage=ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit' and text()='Continue']"));


        //Navbar Elements + MainPage Elements
        final WebElement UsernameMenu_Navbar=ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='navbar-link']"));
        final WebElement ManagementConsoleMenu_UnderNavbar=ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='navbar-link' and text()='Management Console']"));
        final WebElement Logout_UnderNavbar=ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='navbar-link' and text()='Logout']"));

        final WebElement StudentMenu=ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Students']"));


        //Management Console Elements 
        final WebElement DivisionCard_OnManagementConsolePage=ObjectRepo.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Divisions, Classes & Groups']"));

    }


My Subclass is as below:


public class CommonActions extends ObjectRepo 
{
ObjectRepo obj=new ObjectRepo();
public void LaunchUrl() throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(syspath + "/InputData/InputData.xlsx");       
        workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        UserCred=workbook.getSheet("UserCred");
        Browser=workbook.getSheet("Browser");
        Env=workbook.getSheet("Env");
        StudentList=workbook.getSheet("StudentList");
        os=System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(os);

        if(driver == null)
        {
            if(Browser.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue().contains("Chrome"))
            {
                if(os.contains("windows"))
                {System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", syspath + "/Web Driver Exe/chromedriver.exe");}
                else
                {System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", syspath + "/Web Driver Exe/chromedriver");}

                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream=1");       
                options.addArguments("--lang=en");              
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
            else if (Browser.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue().contains("Firefox"))
            {
                if(os.contains("windows"))
                {System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", syspath + "/Web Driver Exe/geckodriver.exe");}
                else
                {System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", syspath + "/Web Driver Exe/geckodriver");}

                FirefoxOptions ffoptions= new FirefoxOptions();
                ffoptions.addPreference("permissions.default.microphone", 1);
                ffoptions.addPreference("permissions.default.camera", 1);   
                ffoptions.addPreference( "intl.accept_languages", "en" ); 

                ffoptions.addPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
                ffoptions.addPreference("browser.download.dir", "syspath");
                ffoptions.addPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
                ffoptions.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");


                driver=new FirefoxDriver(ffoptions);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("No Env selected");
            }
        }
        //Launch Url
        driver.navigate().to(Env.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        QuinnActualTitle=driver.getTitle();
    }


    public void InvokeExcel() throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(syspath + "/InputData/InputData.xlsx");       
        workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        UserCred=workbook.getSheet("UserCred");
        Browser=workbook.getSheet("Browser");
        Env=workbook.getSheet("Env");
    }

    public void CloseExcel() throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(syspath + "/InputData/InputData.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        workbook.close();
        fileOut.close();
    }

    public void Completed()
    {
        driver.close();
        //driver.quit();
    }
public void UniversityAdminLogin(int a, int b) throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        SignIn_SignUp_button.click();   //This is where i m trying to use the declared element
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        EmailField_OnSignIn.sendKeys(UserCred.getRow(a).getCell(b).getStringCellValue());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ContinueButton_OnSignIn.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        PasswordField_OnSignIn.sendKeys(UserCred.getRow(a).getCell(b+1).getStringCellValue());
        ContinueButton_OnPasswordPage.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }


But i see the error while instantiating :
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class SmokeRun.SmokeSuite
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:114)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:172)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:82)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:74)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:39)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:342)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:295)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:226)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:679)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:196)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:127)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1265)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1093)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Sources.ObjectRepo.<init>(ObjectRepo.java:15)
    at Sources.CommonActions.<init>(CommonActions.java:48)
    at SmokeRun.SmokeSuite.<init>(SmokeSuite.java:12)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Not a selenium expert but with some experience. I think the problem might lie with webElements being null and not a driver. Instead of using fields try using methods and refind elements as needed. Take my comment with a grain of salt.

At which point do you create /

When I tried

Comment: The below thing worked:
In the ObjectRepo class - I defined all the elements with By
  By SignIn_SignUp_button = By.xpath("//button[text()='SIGN IN / SIGN UP']");

And kept the driver static in the same CommonActions class  and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, I think the issue is that when you construct a new `ObjectRepo` through: `ObjectRepo obj=new ObjectRepo()`, the driver tries to find those final elements but it fails to do so because the driver initialization is done right below in your subclass. So your assumption that the driver is `null` is correct from what I see.

What I would suggest is to use a debugger, put a breakpoint exactly at the line that fails and check if the driver is `null` or not. I believe you are using some sort of IDE, so take a look here: https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php if you are using eclipse, or here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-code.html if you are using IDEA.